# Gitweb failure: fatal: missing object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for refs/heads/master

Tags: git, gitolite, gitweb

I'm trying to use gitweb with a set of repositories that are managed with gitolite. We can successfully clone/push/pull from them over ssh with no problems. When I try to view the index page, I get the following errors in the apache log:

`fatal: missing object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for refs/heads/master, referer: http://gitwebbox/gitweb/?p=mlp2.git;a=summary`

I've run git fsck and it doesn't find any issues. The ref for master points to a hash that exists in the object tree.

Can anybody help me figure out what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131385/anyone-familiar-with-the-git-error-missing-object-00000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

Particularly given that you are managing the repository with gitolite, you probably should verify the permissions on your repository and verify you can access it as your apache user.

You can also refer to the detailed instructions on [configuring gitolite and gitweb](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/gitolite-gitweb-http-backend.mkd).

Comment: Permissions are ok. Apache user can read and access all dirs. There are other repos in gitolite that work fine with gitweb.